# send a consult to one url but the JSON return is null always

Tags: android, mysql, json

i have a problem i try to extract info of one php in my server but the response is null always

i attach the code that i use next, I'm new in android but i think that the PC don't send anything to the app

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://10.69.44.108/odin/mobile/json/";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

JSONArray user = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

        //Importing TextView
        final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
        final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uid.setText(id);
        name1.setText(name);
        email1.setText(email);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android you are not allowed to perform network operation on main thread:

you cant do :

```
// Getting JSON from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

in `onCreate`, you have to put it in an [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

---

you can do it quick and dirty like this (not tested!):

```
//Importing TextView
final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

new AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, JSONObject>(){
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String ... Urls) {
    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(Urls[]);
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        // do somthing
        return null
    }
        return json;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
     try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uid.setText(id);
        name1.setText(name);
        email1.setText(email);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.execute(url);
```